# Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on array

Tags: php, html, dom

Here is a php code that has to get information from a webpage and echo it.
On the webpage there are 3 div whose class names are "skaties-starfm-songs-column" and in each of them there is one ul. My goal is to echo all the li in ul that are in the first "skaties-starfm-songs-column". But i don't know how to do it.

Web page html code:
I can't post this one as a code because inside it's giant.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oE70R.png)

```
<?php 

include_once 'includes/db.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/simple_html_dom.php';
include_once 'includes/curl_init.php';
$html=curl_get('https://skaties.lv/starfm/dziesmu-top/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom = str_get_html($html);
$songs=$dom->find('.skaties-starfm-songs-column');
foreach ($songs->getElementsByTagName('ul')->getElementsByTagName('li') as $a) {
    echo $a;
}
<?
```

This code posts and error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on array".

```
<?php 

include_once 'includes/db.inc.php';
include_once 'includes/simple_html_dom.php';
include_once 'includes/curl_init.php';
$html=curl_get('https://skaties.lv/starfm/dziesmu-top/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom = str_get_html($html);
$songs=$dom->find('.skaties-starfm-songs-column');
foreach ($songs as $a) {
    echo $a;
}
?>
```

This code echoes all 3 divs with everything that is inside of them.

Comment: Post code as text, here. Not as links to images.

Comment: If you dont bother to post your code, no one will bother to write an answer.

Comment: If you're new, take a moment to read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This helps us to help you and maximises your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: thank you, for the advice next time i will post code from the start not a picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously $songs is an array of divs. If you need just the first one, then use index:

```
$songs[0]->getElementsByTagName('ul');
```

It would be a good idea to check if $songs array is not empty before that:

```php
if (!empty($songs)) {
    $songs[0]->getElementsByTagName('ul');
}
```

Please note that *DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName* method returns DOMNodeList object which is collection-like. Thus if you want some specific , then you should use [DOMNodeList::item](http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php) method:

```
$myLists = $songs[0]->getElementsByTagName('ul');

// get only the first UL element
$firstList = $myLists->item(0);
foreach ($firstList->getElementsByTagName('li') as $a) {
    echo $a;
}

// or walk through all of them
foreach ($myLists as $list) {
    foreach ($list->getElementsByTagName('li') as $a) {
        echo $a;
    }
}
```